# SEO - 2 websites in the same domain

Tags: seo, google, domains, google-search-console, google-search

I have my domain (http://www.foobar.com, for example) and my website talks about technology. I want to have another website (with other content, not about technology) inside of it (http://www.foobar.com/loremipsum). I can find http://www.foobar.com in Google Search, but http://www.foobar.com/loremipsum no ... What should I do to index this website? Thank you.

**update**

My main site (http://www.foobar.com/, a WordPress installation) has an `.httaccess`:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Does it affect the index of http://www.foobar.com/loremipsum ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

1) [Submit the main page to Google directly](http://www.google.com/addurl/?continue=/addurl)

2) Submit an [XML sitemap](http://sitemaps.org/)

3) Link to those inner pages from anywhere. The main website or any other external website will do.

FYI, ideally you'll get a second domain name for that website. It will give you more SEO opportunities and make it clearer to users that these are two separate websites.

**update**

That will have no effect on the indexing of those pages

Comment: U'm using a txt sitemap (Sitemap.txt), is it valid? The site has just 3 pages ...

Comment: You can validate your sitemap in Google Webmaster Tools. If that site is just three pages then I can see why it's not indexed yet. It might have visibility issues. Get links to that content. Force Google to find it and index it. (assuming it isn't duplicate content or anything like that).

Comment: How do I "force" Google to catch that? Thank you very much.

Comment: Get links to that content. Ideally from related websites. But if you can do that then even web directories will do. But get links to those pages.