# SEO - 2 websites in the same domain

Tags: search, google, seo, domains, google-search-console

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SEO - 2 websites in the same domain](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/11413/seo-2-websites-in-the-same-domain)

I have my domain (http://www.foobar.com, for example) and my website talks about technology. I want to have another website (with other content, not about technology) inside of it (http://www.foobar.com/loremipsum). I can find http://www.foobar.com in Google Search, but http://www.foobar.com/loremipsum no ...
What should I do to index this website?
Thank you.

Comment: This question belongs to http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Have you given a sitemap to Google, and are there links from http://www.foobar.com to http://www.foobar.com/loremipsum ?

If not you need to get some links to allow Google etc to actually find the sub pages - you can do that with your sitemap, or you can provide a link across from your main page.

If they're completely separated with no links back and forth, wouldn't they be better on separate domains, or on a subdomain: loremipsum.foobar.com  Of course you'd still have to provide the way for Google to find it in the first place.